# How to find a document within a time range of recorded embedded document?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document that looks something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e5044ecf9d7954533000002"), "events" : [
        {
                "state" : 1,
                "time" : 1313882989,
        },
        {
                "time" : 1313883005,
                "state" : 0,
        }
]}
```

You can see that "events" is an array of embedded documents. state:1 means that the document was set to "active" at that time (seconds in UTC), and state:0 means that it was set "inactive" at that time. This essentially give me a time range of when this document was active (from 1313882989 to 1313883005)

Now Im trying to determine what documents were active at any particular time, like at 1313883013, a time that falls between the active and inactive events.

I can get something with this query:

```
db.plays.find({events:{$elemMatch:{state:1,time:{$lte:1313883013}}}})
```

It matches a complete embedded document where state=1 AND time<1313883013. This is not enough however, because I need to ensure that the document ***also does not contain*** an inactive event at or before 1313883013. So I've tried this:

```
db.plays.find({events:{$elemMatch:{state:1,time:{$lte:1313883013}},$not:{$elemMatch:{state:0,time:{$lte:1313883013}}}}})
```

but to no avail. And I've tried different variations of that as well.

I hope I've made this clear enough, thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

Just don't include state:1 in your query.

From the result you get, check the value of state (0 or 1).